# Convert Raw image(cr2, etc.) to jpg

Tags: flutter

When I try to use raw images, I get errors. I need to somehow convert Raw images to jpg for using it here:

```
File photo = photoData.file;

Container(
     width: 80,
     height: 80,
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
         image: DecorationImage(
             image: FileImage(photo),
             fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ),
     ),
),
```

How can I solve this problem? If there any built-in functions? Or libraries that can help. Also C++ libraries are welcome.